# IP board forum question

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, get

if you ever used an IP board forum you can see that you can click on "quote" for every message you want to quote and once you go in the "add reply" page you'll have the quotes automatically in your answer form. I checked with firebug that once you click on quote no HTTP script is called (like via AJAX to store the quotes id in a session) nor the info is sent to the other page via GET. So how is this quotes info passed to another page?

Comment: That's a good question! Probably the link contains some type of id that references to the post you're quoting?

Comment: No it doesn't. I also tried to click on quote on one message and then open another different thread and add a reply. The quote is the form like this too!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that IP Board is using [Cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) through JavaScript.

Comment: I checked, no cookie seems to be changed

Comment: That's all I can think of, other than `localStorage`.